# Opening every mailbox in read-only mode in Mutt

Tags: email, read-only, mutt, neomutt

I’d like to use Mutt (or NeoMutt, if that makes a difference) to view maildirs in read-only mode.

I know that I can use the `-R` command-line argument to start Mutt in read-only mode, or press the `%` key to toggle between read-only and read-write mode, but this setting seems to reset every time I open a different folder. Can I force it to stay read-only all the time? I wouldn’t want to accidentally modify the mailbox just because I forgot to hit `%` after opening a folder.

Also, I don’t want to use a filesystem-based approach, e.g. `chmod`ing all of the files and directories to be read-only, since they *will* indeed be modified by other tools – but simply reading them should not change them in any way.

To reproduce, start `mutt -R` in the default mailbox. When using the default status bar, there will be a `%` sign at the left, marking the mailbox to be opened read-only. Then use `c` to open another (or even the same) folder. The `%` sign is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an configuration option for that. Add following line to your config:

```
set read_only = yes
```

Docs: [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#read-only), [neomutt](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference.html#3-304-%C2%A0read_only)

```
read_only
    Type: boolean
    Default: no

    If set , all folders are opened in read-only mode.
```

Comment: Oh dear, that was too easy. I swear I’ve googled for it extensively before! Thanks.